# Point in polygon algorithm explanation

Tags: algorithm, matlab, polygon, point

Hi I came across this algorithm from [Mathhelpforum](http://mathhelpforum.com/geometry/42487-point-inside-outside-polygon.html) which determines whether a point is inside or outside a polygon. The code works perfectly so far but I don't fully understand the logic. Kindly provide an explanation if you do, especially on the method...whether ray casting, or winding number, etc. Thanks.

```
function [ inside ] = inpoly(polygon,xt,yt)

rows = size(polygon);
npoints = rows(1);
disp (npoints);
inside = 0;

xold = polygon(npoints,1);
yold = polygon(npoints,2);

for i = 1:1:npoints

   xnew = polygon(i,1);
   ynew = polygon(i,2);

      if (xnew > xold) 
         x1=xold;
         x2=xnew;
         y1=yold;
         y2=ynew;
      else 
         x1=xnew;
         x2=xold;
         y1=ynew;
         y2=yold;
      end

      if ((xnew < xt) == (xt <= xold) & (yt-y1)*(x2-x1) < (y2-y1)*(xt-x1) ) 
               inside=~inside;
      end

      xold=xnew;
      yold=ynew;

end

endfunction
```

To test the function e.g. :

```
inpoly([p,q],x,y)
```

Where p and q are vertices of the polygon and x, y coordinates of the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems a ray casting to me. Varaibles `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2` are the polygon side's endpoints sorted with respect to X. The condition `(xnew < xt) == (xt <= xold)` tests whether the Y-parallel line from the point `xt,yt` meets the side. The other part of the condition tests if `xt,yt` is at the proper side of the polygon's side.

Condition

```
(yt-y1)*(x2-x1) < (y2-y1)*(xt-x1)
```

is equivalent to

```
(yt-y1)*(x2-x1) - (y2-y1)*(xt-x1) < 0
```

which is a matrix determinant

```
| yt-y1  xt-x1 |
|              | < 0
| y2-y1  x2-x1 |
```

and the matrix is a vector cross product

```
(pointT - point1) times (point2 - point1)
```

Comment: Thanks @CiaPan, much clearer to me  now. This implementation of Ray-casting seems rather simple. It works when the point lies within the polygon but doesn't work when the point lies on the edge or a vertex.